# on end listener for property animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606498/end-animation-event-android) question shows how you set listeners for an android view animation, but it doesn't work for property animations.

How can I achieve the same thing with a property animation?

my animation:

```
ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator = layout.animate().y(integer).setInterpolator(interpolator).setStartDelay(delay).setDuration(duration);
```

Comment: check this one may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283074/android-rotateanimation-completed/32283142#32283142

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Yeah, that one is only for view animations.

Comment: Notice it is `Animator.AnimatorListener` not `Animation.AnimationListener`

Comment: still get the message: Cannot resolve method: "addListener(anonymous android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener)"

Comment: Thanks a lot, that small change made all the difference.